# DELETING CLICKED ROW IN CUSTOM LISTVIEW

Tags: android

I need help figuring out why the following code will not delete a clicked row in my Custom ListView.

Basically, I have two classes that I'm working with. Contacts and CustomAdapter. In my Contacts Class I have an onActivityResult() method, which gets data from a different activity and places it in a Custom ListView using my CustomAdapter Class. The data gets added fine. I have an onItemClickListener method that is set after my contactList sets its CustomAdapter. Ideally the method should delete  the specific row that is pressed. I've tried a number of different things but nothing seems to be working. I;m getting the rows to delete with the code below BUT IT"S ONLY DELETING THE LAST ROW ADDED vs one that I click.

I placed the code below. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

onActivityResult in Contacts Class:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            String phone = data.getStringExtra("phone");
            final String email = data.getStringExtra("email");
            //These are array lists declared earlier
            phoneNums.add(phone);
            names.add(name);
            emails.add(email);

            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Contacts.this,names,phoneNums,emails);
            contactList.setAdapter(customAdapter);

            contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //IS THIS CODE CORRECT?
                    names.remove(position);
                    phoneNums.remove(position);
                    emails.remove(position);

                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter Entire Class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String>phoneNumbers;
private ArrayList<String>names;
private ArrayList<String>emails;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public CustomAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String>n,ArrayList<String>nums,ArrayList<String>e){
    context = c;
    phoneNumbers = nums;
    names = n;
    emails = e;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long)position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row,null);

        TextView deleteText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowDeleteText);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactName);
        TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
        TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);

        name.setText(names.get(position));
        phone.setText(phoneNumbers.get(position));
        email.setText(emails.get(position));

        deleteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //SHOULD I PLACE CODE TO DELETE THE ROW IN HERE?

            }
        });


    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: What is deleteText? what is it suppose to show and when? your getItem() method should not return the position. You should wrap your should create and object that contains the name, phone and email, and the custom adapter should use an array of those objects instead.

Comment: In your getView method, you should inflate only if view is null but the rest of the code should always be executed.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Wow, you're man! So now I only inflate the view if it's null. What was happening before that prevented the specific row from being deleted?? Is it that every time I added a row, the view would be inflated and that kept the position variable in my Contacts class from properly being updated? I'm just curious how having the inflater get used every time screwed up the program?Thanks!

Comment: You were already inflating the view only if it is null. When the convertView is not null it means the listview is recycling that view. So what ever was showing on that view before the call of getview was not going to change. I am not hundred percent sure why it prevents you from deleting a row though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that looks like this:

```
public class Contact {

private String name;
private String phone;
private String email;

public Contact(String name, String phone, String email){
    this.setName(name);
    this.setPhone(phone);
    this.setEmail(email);

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

Declare an array of Contacts and In your onActivityResult add:

```
contacts.add(new Contact(name,phone,email);
```

Change the listener to this.

```
 contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               contacts.remove(customAdapter.getItem(position));

                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Change your adapter class to this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Contact> contacts){
    this.context = context;
   this.contacts = contacts;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contacts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long)position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    Contact contact = getItem(position);

    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row,null);
    }

    TextView deleteText =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowDeleteText);
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactName);
    TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
    TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);

    name.setText(contact.getName());
    phone.setText(contact.getPhone());
    email.setText(contact.getEmail());

    return view;
}
```

I think it should resolve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Delete it by using your adapter and refresh your view.i think this is more suitable way.